# Javascript onclick fires on page load

Tags: javascript, callback, dom-events

Just starting out with front end development here, but despite my assuredly poor practices I've been enjoying things a lot. Basically I'm trying to add an `onclick` function to an element when the page loads. It was working fine as:

```
$("li a:contains('Search')").ready(function(){
    $("li a:contains('Search')").on("click", function(){
$("li a:contains('Search)").text("test")});
});
```

But my programmer spidey-senses were strongly activated by the quite frankly gross state of this code, so I tried to refactor and my thought for the easiest first-step refactoring was this:

```
function replaceWithSearch(element){
    element.text("test");
}

$("li a:contains('Search')").ready(function(){
    $("li a:contains('Search')").on("click", replaceWithSearch($("li a:contains('Search')")));
});
```

However, when I changed to that, the `onclick` function now launches immediately. Is there a way to force the function to only be evaluated when called as a callback? I would prefer to have the function be reusable, also if you have any other comments on refactoring my code or best practices I would be very glad to hear them. Again, just starting out with Javascript and I would love to build some good practices.

Comment: I've never seen .ready() in this context. It's usually on document ready, which then calls a function to set up the event handlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimized code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li a:contains('Search')").bind("click", function() {
        $(this).text("test");
    });
});
```

If you prefer to use a function, proper way is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li a:contains('Search')").bind("click", replaceWithSearch);
});
```

And in the function you don't have to use argument:

```
function replaceWithSearch(){
    $(this).text("test");
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/TJ2TT/).

If your elements are created after page load, use the `.on()` like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "li a:contains('Search')", replaceWithSearch);
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TJ2TT/2/).

Comment: Oh, fantastic. Thanks so much for this. Great explanation, and optimized code is much cleaner.

Comment: Cheers @Slater I assume that all elements are fixed, right? Meaning you don't create links on the fly with code?

Comment: Well, done in mako templates rather than js. Is there something I should watch out for?

Comment: If the elements are created after page load you need to use the `.on()`, will edit my post now.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the handler in a function like:

```
$("li a:contains('Search')").ready(function(){
    $("li a:contains('Search')").on("click", function() {replaceWithSearch($("li a:contains('Search')"))});
});
```

That way, the handler is defined and associated with the click event, rather than executing immediately.